# How do you react to a row click in ng-grid?

Tags: ng-grid

I want to react to a row click; I don't want the checkbox/select things, I just want to know when a particular row was clicked. Where do I put the hook for that?

Comment: Have you tried to place it at the `<TR>` tag?

Comment: You haven't chosen an accepted answer on 12 out of your 16 questions. It  would be kind of you to either accept the best answer on those posts or leave feedback if the answers need to be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use afterSelectionChange.

```
gridOptions.afterSelectionChange = function (rowItem) {
     var entity = rowItem.entity;
     // CODE
};
```